# How to get mouse position with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, mouse, puppeteer

I'am trying to open a page with puppeteer, and in that page I want to move the mouse in that page to the position of the current mouse that iam using, but i cant find anything, so i was wondering if it was possible

Answer (score 3):

You can get the coordinates of the mouse by this way:

```js
page.evaluate(() => {
   document.onmousemove = function(e){
           mouseX = e.offsetX;
           mouseY = e.offsetY;
           console.log(mouseX, mouseY);
   }
})
```